# Regex to find semicolon (;) between quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that find a semicolon (`;`) between two double quotes (`""`). The corresponding regex that I found is the following :

```
;(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

Here is an example : https://regexr.com/40lhm

The problem is that this corresponding regex is not working when a single double quote (`"`) is found in the string. When such a case happened, it's actually returning the whole sequence of `;`.

Example of the problem : https://regexr.com/40n3c

Comment: just use this \";\"

Comment: I need to find the ";" that is between two quote (" ; "). It's use to parse a csv file. The problem is when this happend : Patrick;Pierre;"coco; coco"; "Patrick

Comment: @Astrus then [edit] your question with proper input please.

Comment: `"\s*;\s*"` should do the trick

Comment: Thomas you can see that your regex is not working at all : regexr.com/40n4s

Comment: What do you want to match in this example? I see no trace of `double quote` `space(s)` `;` `space(s)` `double quote`.

Answer (score -1):

if i am correct this is what you wanted to achieve:

[image]

i used the following :

```
(?<=")[";]+(?=")
```

Comment: after @ThomasAyoub remarks i changed it to : (?<=")[";"]+(?=") this only allows a ; between " "

Comment: Or `"""`, `"""""""""`, `";;;;;;"`. But that's better?

Comment: `[";"]` makes no sense. Character classes only need each character once. Either use `[";]` or don't use a character class at all.

Comment: the fact that you guys are complain does not change the fact that he uses a CSV file to get data. i hope he uses a certain standard in his CSV file. so what is the point to exclude all these thing. if these cases are never gonna get realised. something you have to say, this ok for this project.

Comment: @Corion that is correct. but for people who just start with regex it makes it easier to read.

Comment: No, using `[";"]+`just confuses people and makes them think that character classes work differently from how they do work. Please don't teach such bad habits.